# SSAS compare 2 YTD values for same month in different years

Tags: excel, ssas, mdx

I am developing a cube in SSAS, I need to be able to compare YTD values between current year and last year.

**I have the below scenario:**

- Budget types by year : **budget1-2016** , **budget2-2016** ,**budget1-2017**
  , **budget2-2017**.
- The budget types should be placed in the columns
- Units: should be placed in the rows
- The measure is called "Billings"

I  need to compare  YTD value for "Billings" between budgets "budget1 - 2016" and  "budget2-2017" (different budget types and year) for a specific month.

when the Calendar month is included in the rows or columns everything works fine,[image: Expected Result]

but if it is included in the filter and I choose for example February 2016 and February 2017, the results are not as expected.

[image] 
[image]

With the usage of the TAIL function, only the higher month is taken into consideration and the column from 2016 is removed.

Is there a way to put the calendar month in the filter, select same month from different years and be able to see their YTD values?

Comment: Do you use any calculation on your Measures.Billings?

Comment: I am using an expression for the measure : _Billings = _Billings*Rate
. The YTD value is calculated as follows :
Sum(PeriodsToDate([Data Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year],[Data Date].[Calendar].CURRENTMEMBER),[Measures].[_Billings])

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you put two members in the filter. **CurrentMember** doesn't work with two tuples. Hence **[Data Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember** is **[Data Date].[Calendar].DefaultMember** is **[Data Date].[Calendar].[All]**. It runs the following code:

```
Sum(
    PeriodsToDate(
        [Data Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year],
        [Data Date].[Calendar].[All]
    ),
    [Measures].[_Billings]
)
```

You are choosing two month from different year, thus it's unclear what do you want to return from the **PeriodsToDate()** function. The data since January 2016 or January 2017? Choosing one of the members will fix your problem and make it clear.

I don't guarantee that's the perfect code to work with, but it may does the magic as well, add yet another calculated members to sum months:

```
Sum(
    existing [Data Date].[Month].[Month].Members,
    [Measures].[Billings]
)
```

Comment: I need the data since Jan 2016 for budget1-2016 and since Jan 2017 for budget 2017. In summary, I need to compare YTD values for budget1 for year 2016 against budget 2 for year 2017 on the same month of the year.

Comment: If you add the third member, say, July 2016 there. Will it return sum of all these tree members? It means that January 2016 billing value will be included twice. I thing you conception is wrong.  I've updated my answer with a dirty workaround, but try to consider another way to deal it.

Comment: The workaround did not wok either. No need to implement this anymore. Adding the calendar month in the columns or rows will be enough for the client.